# how can I generate all possible outcomes of a dynamically loaded database?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I'm having a bit of trouble with this one..

I need to generate all possible outcomes of a dynamically loaded database like this one..

```
COLOUR  SIZE    FABRIC
blue    small   denim
red     medium  cotton
green   large   wool
```

ok.. so for example this database (above) gets set up by the user the rows and columns can be added so I don't know how many rows/columns I'm dealing with.

If it was just 3 columns by x amount of rows I could just set up a for loop i.e. keep adding x until it goes though all rows, then increment y until that goes though all columns, then increment z etc...

But being as I don't know how many rows are in the database I can't find a way of referencing the array..

I hope I've explained myself well enough for you to understand, I'm pretty new to programming and I've been trying to figure this one out for hours.

Comment: No, your explanation is terrible. What database you're talking about? is it flat text file or form input or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate/generate a string with all possible values in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335886/how-to-calculate-generate-a-string-with-all-possible-values-in-an-array) . I saw the three same questions in the last 24 hours. Is this a homework?

Comment: Sorry, I know the explanation is bad. It's a mySQL database, the collumns and rows are generated from form input. I then need to get all possible outcomes of this database and put them into another database, ie if it's 3 rows by 3 collums it's 3X3X3=27 possible outcomes.

Comment: @ajreal.. no, this isn't homework..

Comment: What is it then? There is no sensible practical meaning in this task

Comment: What is the OUTCOME that you are expecting ? and i really dont understand this part of your question :: "If it was just 3 columns by x amount of rows I could just set up a for loop i.e. keep adding x until it goes though all rows, then increment y until that goes though all columns, then increment z etc..."...  mind rephrasing it ?

Comment: I'm creating an ecommerce site, and I want to be able to give a product different options. I want the admin to be able to define the options, and be able to alter properties ie 'price' of each of the possible outcomes. I suppose I'd have to try to simulate nested for loops to be able to do this,

Answer (score 1):

JOIN = Cartesian product

```
select * from 
(select distinct colour from TBL) as t1 join 
(select distinct size from TBL)   as t2 join 
(select distinct fabric from TBL) as t3
order by colour, size, fabric;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. It's exactly what I need! I didn't think of doing it to the actual table it's self.