# Storing cartesian product results in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thanks for reading, I hope this makes sense! I am trying to modify a bespoke CMS which gives different product options and lets you set various attributes based on combinations of those options. These are getting pulled from a mySQL database. For example, a t-shirt might have:

```
Colour         Size       
------         ----
Red            Small
Red            Medium
Blue           Small
Blue           Medium
```

Each colour and size would have a unique ID so red = 1, blue = 2 and small = 3, medium = 4. Colour and Size would each have a parent id, so colour = 1, size = 2.

At the moment I am storing a string in a database table in the database that identifies each combination (e.g. Red + small would be &1=1&2=3). This string then associates this combination of options with various attributes: price, stock code etc.

However the problem comes when we want to add a new option group to the mix, say sleeve length. At the moment this would mean having to go through the strings and changing them to also include the new option. This seems like a very inefficient and long-winded way to be doing this!

So (eventually!) my question is - is there a better way I can be doing this ? I need to ensure that there is no real limit on the number of option groups that can be added, as well as letting new option groups be added at any time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Stuart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337041/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-outcomes-of-a-dynamically-loaded-database/7337500#7337500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would counter instead with asking you, why would you want to store that in the first place?

Cartesian products are a controller issue, not a domain model one. Your domain model (your database) should only care to keep the data in a normalized fashion (or as close as it's feasible), let the database system do the joins as needed (`inner join` in sql), that's what they're optimized to do in the first place.

Comment: Indeed. Leave the data as it is, and do a CROSS JOIN when grabbing the data. (@stukerr: Leaving aside the issue that INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN are interchangeable in MySQL, it's traditionally a CROSS JOIN that's used to explicitly generate a Cartesian product, so that might help you search out the syntax you want. And you could use that to generate your wanted static data table, as well as doing it dynamially as Blindy suggests.)

Comment: The reason why I think I need this is (a bit long!) : The actual groups (such as colour) and options (such as red) are stored in tables in the database already, however I am tying this in to a system which uses a single stock code for a combination of options (so e.g. Red/Small is stock code 1001, Red/Medium is 1002, Blue/Small is 1011 etc.). I need to store the options separately so they can be listed in drop downs (one for colour, one for size etc.) but I need some way to tie this back to the stock code as this hold information such as price, quantity etc. - I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @stukerr, consider making merged ID's then, something like `comboID = (colorID<<8) | sizeID`. My point stands, this is a presentation issue, not a database backing issue.